# Appending string swift?

Tags: swift, string

I am trying here to build long string that i will be using to post data using http problem is when i call this function i get the error **Thread Exception** . I think this might be bad practice , which is other way to build string in swift ?

```
import Foundation

public var link: String!
public var entryData = NSDictionary()
public var postData : String! = ""
var data:String! = ""
var data2:String! = ""

public func setLink(text:String)
{
    postData.appendContentsOf(text)
}

public func setFirstField(entry:String,value:String) {
    data = "\(entry)=\(value)"
    postData.appendContentsOf(data)
}

public func setNextFields(entry:String,value:String)
{
    data2 = "&\(entry)=\(value)"
    postData.appendContentsOf(data2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API.

`appendContentsOf` is a generic which expects an **array** of the same type.

In your case just replace

```
postData.appendContentsOf(text)
```

with

```
postData.append(text)
```

or still simpler

```
postData += text
```

PS: I highly recommend to use `(NS)URL` and `(NS)URLComponents` / `(NS)URLQueryItem` for that purpose.

And **do not** use implicit unwrapped optionals for obviously non-optional strings.

Answer (score 0):

What i was doing wrong that it was out of class. So what i did is put everything inside of one class and while calling getting instance.

```
let gPost = Post()
gPost.setLink()
```